# Redirect to login when user is not connect

Tags: laravel

When i want to access to a page in my application i get an exception when i'm not logged in

> ErrorException in ec75fc198343b0a46e649467428bd2d5f829caf1.php line 49:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

Should i make a route middleware group ?

I would like when i want to access to the pages when i'm not logging that the app redirect me directly to the login form without display me this error message !

Someone know how to do that ?

Comment: Yes, you should either do this in a middleware or in your controller. A guest should not be able to render this view.

Comment: did you use laravel's Auth?

Comment: yeap !!! i use Laravel Auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the `auth` middleware for the action that is responsible for rendering the page. There are multiple ways how you can accomplish this in Laravel. Here are a few of them:

In the routes file for a particular action

```php
Route::get('your/page', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'YourPageController@index']);
```

or the same thing fluently

```php
Route::get('your/page', 'YourPageController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

In the routes file for a group of actions/pages

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], function () {
    Route::get('your/page', 'YourPageController@index');
});
```

In the controller

```php
class YourPageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth'); // you can pass an array of actions/methods that should not be covered by the auth middleware in a second parameter ['except' => 'someaction']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! i tried this , i actually use adminlte for the template when i try to run the page with the middleware i get Route [adminlte::login] not defined. do you know why i get this issue ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code but I 'd guess that you don't have a named `login` route in your routes file. Something along the lines of `Route::get('login', 'Auth/LoginController@login')->name('login');` See how at the end the name is being assigned to this route by using the `name()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Kernel.php and add this to the protected $routeMiddleware part at the end:

```
 'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

Then in your routes you can use this 'auth' to check if the user is logged in.

For example:

```
Route::get('/example', 'YourController@getExample')->middleware('auth');
```

if you don't have a middleware or you have any trouble follow this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Include the Middleware in routes.

```
Route::get('/Demo','DemoLine@index')->middleware('auth');
```